# Promql for getting percentage stats for http status codes

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, promql

I would like to plot a graph and add it dashboard for displaying percentage of 2xx, 4xx and 5xx (and even grouped by specific http status codes like 401, 503, 502, 500 etc.) based on http status codes. I'm trouble having building a query to achieve the desired result. Can someone please help providing the query or suggestions?

I have tired the following query but getting results in not per my expectation.

```
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="xxxx", status=~"2..", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m])) 
/ 
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="xxxx", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m]))
* 100
```

Kindly assit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the result and what's ur expectation?

Comment: On the first glance your query looks ok. Though if you want to get results grouped by code you should replace first  part with `sum by(status) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="xxxx", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m]))`

Comment: @markalex yes but need is we need to compute the percentage of each http status where I'm getting issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grafana I've seen this normally done using a query for each status code group, but you could do something like this:

```
sum by (new_code) (
  label_replace(
    rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="xxxx", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m]),
    "new_code",
    "${1}xx",
    "status",
    "(^\\d).+"
  )
) / 
scalar(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="xxxx", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m]))) * 100
```

First, we extract the first digit of the status code into the `new_code` label and then we aggregate over the prefix label with the `sum by()`.

Then we need to divide by the total number of requests, we make sure to ignore any label by transforming it into a scalar value using the `scalar()` function.

You can check [this example](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=sum%20by%20(new_code)%20(label_replace(rate(caddy_http_request_duration_seconds_count%7Binstance%3D%22localhost%3A2019%22%7D%5B2m%5D)%2C%20%22new_code%22%2C%20%22%24%7B1%7Dxx%22%2C%20%22code%22%2C%20%22(%5E%5C%5Cd).%2B%22))%0A%2F%0Ascalar(sum(rate(caddy_http_request_duration_seconds_count%7Binstance%3D%22localhost%3A2019%22%7D%5B2m%5D)))%20*%20100&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h) which points to the prometheus demo instance. Keep in mind that the example is using the `caddy_http_request_duration_seconds_count` metric because `http_server_requests_seconds_count` is not present there.

Comment: Hi @Jorge, thanks for sharing this info. That scalar function helped me, thanks!