Calculate QoS(Quality of Service) in % in Grafana using PromQl
I have a nodejs application with counter and histogram as well setup like this:
this.express.use((req, res, next) => {
            const start = Date.now();
            res.on('finish', () => {
                const route = req.route?.path || 'unknown_route';
                loggerService.debug(`[app.ts] Request sent to telemetry ♻ ${req.method} ${route} ${res.statusCode} ${Date.now() - start}ms`);
                const duration = Date.now() - start;
                httpRequestDurationMilliseconds
                    .labels(req.method, route, String(res.statusCode))
                    .observe(duration);
                httpRequestsTotal
                    .labels(req.method, route, String(res.statusCode))
                    .inc();
            });
            next();
        });

export const httpRequestDurationMilliseconds = new promClient.Histogram({
    name: 'http_request_duration_milliseconds',
    help: 'Duration of HTTP requests in milliseconds',
    labelNames: ['method', 'route', 'code'],
    buckets: [1, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000]
});

export const httpRequestsTotal = new promClient.Counter({
    name: 'http_requests_total',
    help: 'Count of all HTTP requests',
    labelNames: ['method', 'route', 'code'],
});


I want to calculate something fairly easy which is the quality of service or QoS. This should be in % and I want to have routes and methods.
I have tried several queries but I cannot make it work:
(
  sum(rate(http_requests_total{code=~"2.."}[$__rate_interval])) by (route, method)
  /
  sum(rate(http_requests_total[$__rate_interval])) by (route, method)
) * 100

The above provides only success requests. I want to visualise a deviation of each route-method combination in %.
I do see the logs like:
DEBUG [app.ts] Request sent to telemetry ♻ POST /api/v1/auth/register 400 78ms
DEBUG [app.ts] Request sent to telemetry ♻ POST /api/v1/faqs 401 3ms

but for some reason I cannot see or complete the time series graph.
The formula I use for QoS is:
QoS (%)= (Number of Successful Requests / Total number of requests) × 100

Do I have to setup 2 counters for this? Can someone help?

Can you clarify, does your sum(rate(..))/sum(rate(..))*100 query work or not? If yes, then what is not showing result? If no do separate sum(rate) parts give any result?

the query itself does work but it shows only the success requests and I do not see the drop for failed requests. To provide more context say that I hit endpoint: POST /api/v1/auth/register If I hit 10 times and I get 201 as response and then I hit 5 times and get 400 response I would expect QoS to drop to 50% for this endpoint but I do not see this in the graph at all!

I guess expected percent will be 66, but I got your point. Does query http_requests_total give you any results with codes other than successful ones?

if I only use this query yes it does. However I am now thinking that I do use 3 queries but the idea might be to use 2 queries and then a math expression instead of the 3rd query. I am thinking the logic would roughly be like:
Query A = sum(rate(http_requests_total{code=~"2.."}[$__rate_interval])) by (route)
Query B = sum(rate(http_requests_total[$__rate_interval])) by (route)
Expression = QA/QB * 100

@matrix Maybe a query similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77543927/1977773 would work in this case? The query works automatically for all the status codes reported by your metric and the total is calculated without any route, so each status code is evaluated against the total requests reported by the service.
